# Split comma delimited string into smaller ones

Tags: .net-2.0

How would I split a comma delimited string into smaller comma delimited strings?

My string looks like this: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

And I need to split the string after every nth occurrence of the `,` character.
E.g. for every 3rd occurrence, the above string would be turned into these strings:
`1,2,3,4` `5,6,7,8` `9,10`

Might look like homework but it's not, my brain is just tired but I still need to get work done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a loop in which you count the commas ;-)

Untested, it could look like:

```
int lastSplit = 0;
int commaCount = 0;
int n = 4;
List<string> parts = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
   if (s[i] == ',' && ++commaCount == n)
   {
      commaCount = 0;
      parts.Add(s.Substring(lastSplit, i - lastSplit));
      lastSplit = i + 1;
   }
}

parts.Add(s.Substring(lastSplit));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via regex.  Try out `((?:[^,]+)(?:,(?:(?:[^,]*))){0,3})` on [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Oh, and then you just need to swap out the "3" in the regex for whatever number of commas you need.

Answer (score 0):

So?

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void test()
  {

          string text = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
          var lists = Regex.Matches(text, ".,.,.,.");

          foreach (var x in lists)
          {
             Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
          }

  }
```